# issue with post(create a record) webapi in blazor server app

Tags: c#, postman, blazor, blazor-server-side, webapi

I create a blazor server app project and I am using built in webapi framework

I am checking a create record webapi in **postman** but it give a 204 content means my webapi run but it return 204 content see below image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdfFc.png]     //webapi test in postman but it return 204 content

[image: postman->header(Content-Type-application/json)]

**blazor server app**

EmpsController.cs

```
namespace CrudBlazorServerApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmpsController : ControllerBase
    {       
        private readonly sqldbcontext _context;

        public EmpsController(sqldbcontext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Emps
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Emp>>> Getemps()
        {
            return await _context.emps.ToListAsync();
        }
        
        // GET: api/Emps/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Emp>> GetEmp(int id)
        {
            var emp = await _context.emps.FindAsync(id);

            if (emp == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return emp;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Emp>> PostEmp(Emp emp)  //here I am facing issue record is not created
        {
            _context.emps.Add(emp);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetEmp", new { id = emp.empid }, emp);
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
namespace CrudBlazorServerApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            
            services.AddControllers()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true);
            services.AddDbContext<sqldbcontext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlserverconnn")));
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<sqldbcontext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseCors(policy =>
    policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44399")  // client address 
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .WithHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentType));
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Database Diagram]

why it give 204 no content?

.net core project version : **netcoreapp3.1**

what I am trying:

I comment this line

```
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

but record not created

please help

which place need to correction?

Comment: Replace `GetEmp` by `GetTemps`. I don't know why, but BaseController return on some case 204. For example `Ok(null)` return 204 : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8847

Comment: @Vernou as you said I change but same response 204 no content see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD0M1.png

Comment: I tested your code and get 201... Maybe the problem is in startup.

Comment: @Vernou what are you saying? I spent 1 day and still give same error? can you help more

Comment: @Vernou  I add my startup.cs in my question see please which place need to correction

Comment: @Vernou can you tell me which place doing I am wrong?\

Comment: I see no error... Try comment `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` and retest.

Comment: @Vernou as you said I comment above line same issue 204 see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip8oV.png

Comment: Can you add the class Emp?

Comment: @Vernou yes see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Nlg.png

Comment: What version of .NET Core?

Comment: @Vernou .net core 3.1

Comment: @Vernou can you identify the problm which place I am made mistake?

Comment: @Vernou very difficulty to find the issue which place need to correction?I am facing this issue last 8 hours
which place need to correction?which place I am made mistake?still not found the solution please help

Comment: I try this and get the expected result... Maybe you can create a minimal project and try reproduce the problem.